# Create Multiple Duplicate Rows Dependent on Column Value in Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a dataset of PTO from different employee like below. The issue is that the entire PTO block is summarized into a multi-day row like below and I need it to be transformed into individual days off.

| Employee_Id | Days_off | PTO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001A | 1 | 10/23/2023 12:00:00 |
| 002B | 2 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 |
| 003C | 3 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 |

I would like to use the column "Days_off" to create the appropriate number of duplicate rows like below so that I can divide the number of hours by the value of Days_off.

| Employee_Id | Days_off | PTO | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001A | 1 | 10/23/2023 12:00:00 | 8 |
| 002B | 2 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 | 16 |
| 002B | 2 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 | 16 |
| 003C | 3 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 | 24 |
| 003C | 3 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 | 24 |
| 003C | 3 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 | 24 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create duplicate you can use `Derived Column` transformation Followed by `Flatten` transformation. In last use select transformation to get exact what you want.**

Steps:

1. Create a dataset and its data like your provided.
   [image]
2. Take Derived column trans formation to create an hour's column and Array of days off column.

```json
hours : multiply(Days_off, 8)
arraydyoffs : mapLoop(Days_off,#index)
```

[image]
[image]

3. Now flatten the `arraydyoffs` which we created in derived column.
   [image]
   [image]

**To get desired output Now take select transformation and delete the `arraydyoffs` column.**

[image]